# Whats wrong in line 6 which make Parse Error?

Tags: json

[Whats wrong in line 6 which  make Parse Error ?][1]

```
{
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "latest"
    }
}
}
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
        "tdd": "npm run test -- --watch --notify"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.15",
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "babel-jest": "^22.1.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jest": "^22.1.4",
        "jest-vue-preprocessor": "^1.3.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.10",
        "pace": "github:HubSpot/pace#v1.0.2",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
        "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
        "sweetalert2": "^7.19.2",
        "tether": "^1.4.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "jest": {
        "roots": ["<rootDir>/tests/Javascript/"],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "^vue$": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": ["js",
        "vue"],
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
            ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-vue-preprocessor"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: now I've formatted the data nicely for you (there are many tools, including [this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) you can use to do that automatically), it should be really quite obvious that you have an extra `}` which doesn't have a matching `{`. I'm going to guess it's just a typo or something. In future try formatting your data so it's readable, and then simple problems like this will become easily visible.

Answer (score 0):

You have closed one extra curly braces in line no: 7